# Laravel modules in subfolder and composer

Tags: php, laravel, module, composer-php

I'm using [Laravel modules by nwidart](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules) and I want to create module in subfolder. According [issue on its Github](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/201) this is not possible but is possible to change paths in `composer.json`. So I've created new module `Role2` and moved it to subfolder `Administration`. Then I've changed module's `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "nwidart/role2",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nicolas Widart",
            "email": "n.widart@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Modules\\Administration\\Role2\\Providers\\Role2ServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {

            }
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Modules\\Administration\\Role2\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

But after command `composer dumpautoload` I see nothing in command `php artisan module:list` and also in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` there is no path to this module. What I'm doing wrong or what is missing to generate multiple composer (one in root and one in module)? Or is there some simple option to have module in subfolder?

There is what I have in root `composer.json`:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database",
      "vendor",
      "app/Easyk"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
      "vendor/swiftmailer"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app",
      "Modules\\": "Modules",
      "Easyk\\": "app/Easyk",
      "Asipem\\OAuth2ClientManagement\\": "packages/asipem/oauth2-client-management/src",
      "Asipem\\CAPRequestDispatcher\\": "packages/asipem/cap-request-dispatcher/src"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\Unit\\": "tests/unit"
    }
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`autoload` -> `psr-4` key from composer.json is used to define psr-4 root namespaces for the application.

What happens is you define a namespace and the directory location for Autoloader to look for the files under that namespace.

As in your root `composer.json`

```
"psr-4": {
  "App\\": "app",
  "Modules\\": "Modules",
  "Easyk\\": "app/Easyk",
  "Asipem\\OAuth2ClientManagement\\": "packages/asipem/oauth2-client-management/src",
  "Asipem\\CAPRequestDispatcher\\": "packages/asipem/cap-request-dispatcher/src"
}
```

`App` is the base namespace and `app` is its base directory. By defining it, you tell autoloader that all files with namespace `App` will be residing inside the directory 'app'. After that, Autoloader will traverse the `app` directory in the `PSR-4` way for file path following the namespace trail after base namespace `App`.

For example: Controller `App\Controller\ExampleController` will tell Autoloader that the class defination will be found at `app/Controller/ExampleController`.

So you need to specify the base directory location of your module against the namespace `Modules\\Administration\\Role2\\` which is the base source directory of your module folder.

Hope it helped.